# ASP.NET MVC - Changing a string value renders it at the point of setting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my view, I'm needing to set a field to highlight red if there is an error in the field. I pass a list of fields in error from the Controller, and conditionally set the class to errorField if there is a match:

```
<td>@(cssClass = errorFields.Contains("Field1") ? "errorField" : "") <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" value="@form.Field1" class="@cssClass" style="width: 5em;" /></td>
```

This works for setting the class value, but the problem is that I also have it rendering as:

```
<td>errorField <input...>
```

Obviously, I don't want errorField to render there. How do I prevent this behavior? I could wrap it in a hidden div, but I feel like that is just a hacky way to fix it (granted, the way I'm handling the conditional CSS may be hacky in the first place).

edit:

Based on David's answer, this is how I went about handling it:

in the model I added a List ErrorFields property.
Also added basically the same method David gave, except due to it handling different fields, it is:

```
public string ErrorCode(string field)
{
   return ErrorFields.Contains(field) ? "errorField" : "");
}
```

Instead of the controller passing the error fields to the ViewBag, it passes it to ErrorFields within the model.

In the view, basically as David gave:

```
class="@form.ErrorCode("Field1")"
```

And it functions appropriately.

Comment: This is the type of thing that should be on the model, not in the view.  The view should just bind to data on the model, and the model should internally set its members.

Comment: Cool. Like I said, I felt it may be hacky in the first place. Do you know where I can find an example similar to this using the model correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this in the view, do this on the model.

In your case you can just have an `ErrorClass` property on the model (or something of similar name).  Something like this:

```
public string ErrorClass
{
    get
    {
        return errorFields.Contains("Field1") ? "errorField" : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then in the view you'd bind to the property:

```
class="@Model.ErrorClass"
```

Without knowing more about your model, it's impossible to be more specific than this.  It's possible that there are multiple classes in this case, which may call for a collection of some sort or perhaps putting the error indicator on a sub-model of which there is a collection in the parent model.  It's also possible (perhaps even likely in this case) that there's simpler built-in validation functionality that can achieve what you're looking for.

The point is, in general, any time you try to do a construct like this in your view:

```
var something = "a value";
```

Then there's a good chance that you're using the view incorrectly and should be putting that in the model instead.